# Windows 10: Limit network file share to specific network(s) only

Tags: windows-10, networking, network-shares

I have the situation, that I would like to share some files/folders from my laptop on my home network, but I don't want to share these when I am connected to any other network.
I know that I can prevent sharing for a specific network card/adapter by disabling the services in the adapter options, but that will not work in this case.
I want to be able to share the files on one wifi network (eg. "Home Wifi"), but not on another wifi network (eg. "Uni Wifi"). As both are wifi networks, the laptop connects to both with its builtin wifi adapter, so enabling/disabling the service on the wifi adapter would enable/disable the sharing on both networks...

Is it possible to do something like this with Windows 10 or 11 (without any extra software)?

Answer (score 0):

Disabling shares according to specific networks (beyond Public/Private) is not a Windows feature that I'm aware of.

The easiest way to accomplish something similar (not sharing with random people on an unknown network) would be to require authentication for the shared folder(s).  You can do this through the context menu of a folder/file (right click) -> Properties -> Sharing -> Advanced Sharing -> Permissions.

You can also hide network shares by appending a '$' character to the end of the share name.

Comment: I was also looking into the permissions option under andvanced sharing and wanted to add the user from my laptop. But when adding a user the Location field says "DESKTOP-PC" (the name of the computer Im on) and when clicking the button next to the field that is also the only option I can select. (The laptop does not show up here) Even though the laptop does show up under the Network 'folder' in explorer.
Any idea how I can get the laptop to show up as a location to select users from?